# Is this the only way we can force ObjectDataSource to…?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, objectdatasource

Greetings,

1) I assume *ObjectDataSource* automatically binds to data source only on first request, but not on  postbacks ( else *ObjectDataSource.Selecting* event would be fired on postbacks also, but it isn’t):

A) So only way to force *ObjectDataSource* to also bind on postbacks is by manually calling *DataBind()*?

2) Assuming *DropDownList1* has *DataSourceID* set to *ObjectDataSource1* , then first time page is loaded, *ObjectDataSource1* will automatically call *DropDownList1.DataBind()* (  after *Page.PreRender* event) and insert retrieved data.

A) But what if we also manually call *DropDownList1.DataBind()* when page is first loaded:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Will *ObjectDataSource1* somehow notice that *DropDownList1.DataBind()* has already be called and thus won’t automatically call *DropDownList1.DataBind()* ?

B) Normally *ObjectDataSource1.Selecting* event is fired after *Page.Prerender* event.But what if *DropDownList1.DataBind()* is called inside *Page_Load()*?

Will in that case *ObjectDataSource1.Selecting* event be fired prior to *Page.PreRender*?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will in that case ObjectDataSource1.Selecting event be fired prior to Page.PreRender?

Yes it is called prior to Page.PreRender.

**Reason:** Each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method in prerender event,

check page life cycle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

http://dotnetshoutout.com/Data-Binding-Events-for-Data-Bound-Controls-in-ASPNet

Since the load event is called before prerender, and when call databind method then in your situation objectdatasource selected event fired before prerender

Comment: I assume if the first time page is loaded  we manually call DropDownList1.DataBind()(inside Page_Load()), then DropDownList1 won't again call DataBind() in PreRender event?!