# gridview loading of data using object data source control

Tags: c#

I have a question for you all, how can I make an object data source load data in to the gridview only when somebody clicks a link button? The main thing I am going to pass some parameters for the select method in the object data source at run time based on the search criteria of the user. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Set the `DataSource` and call `DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx).

Comment: Hi lc, can i assign objectdatasource control to dataset. if anything is there can you suggest me some sample code

Answer (score 0):

Put all parameters in HiddenField's, one of the HDF must be a flag that is used to decide if the select method must return the query items. See this [answer](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11874496WebApp.7z).

Code sample:

FilterGridView.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilterGridView.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Q11876988WebApp.FilterGridView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%--
        Fields for user inputs
        --%>
        &nbsp;Id:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;Phone:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <%--
        Button to perform query
        --%>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnQuery" runat="server" OnClick="BtnQuery_Click" Text="Query" />
        <%--
        Hidden Fields used as parameters
        --%>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfId" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfName" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfPhone" runat="server" />
        <%--'false': Avoid query execution before 'BtnQuery' click.--%>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfDoQuery" runat="server" Value="false" />
        <%--
        GridView
        --%>
        <asp:GridView ID="GrvMyData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="OdsMyData">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <%--
        ObjectDataSource and parameters related to Hidden Fields
        --%>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OdsMyData" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
            SelectMethod="QueryMyDataPoco" TypeName="Q11876988WebApp.FilterGridViewODS">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HdfId" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="id"
                    PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HdfName" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="name"
                    PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HdfPhone" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="phone"
                    PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HdfDoQuery" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="doQuery"
                    PropertyName="Value" Type="Boolean" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

FilterGridView.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class FilterGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    protected void BtnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //change this values causes the 'OdsMyData' 'DataBind'.
        this.HdfId.Value = this.TxtId.Text;
        this.HdfName.Value = this.TxtName.Text;
        this.HdfPhone.Value = this.TxtPhone.Text;
        this.HdfDoQuery.Value = true.ToString();
    }
}
```

FilterGridViewODS.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for a ObjectDataSource
/// </summary>
[DataObject]
public class FilterGridViewODS
{
    private static IList<MyDataPoco> MyDataList = new List<MyDataPoco>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor. Creates a list of 50 items.
    /// </summary>
    static FilterGridViewODS()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            MyDataList.Add(
                new MyDataPoco()
                {
                    Id = i.ToString(),
                    Name = "Name " + i,
                    Phone = i + "" + i + "" + i + "." + i + "" + i + "" + i + "" + i + ""
                });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// if <paramref name="doQuery"/> is <c>true</c>, performs a 
    /// query over the data content, Otherwise return an empty list.
    /// </summary>
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<MyDataPoco> QueryMyDataPoco(String id, String name, String phone, bool doQuery)
    {
        if (doQuery)
        {
            IEnumerable<MyDataPoco> filteredEnum =
                from md in MyDataList
                where
                    md.Id.Contains(id)
                    && md.Name.Contains(name)
                    && md.Phone.Contains(phone)
                select md;

            return filteredEnum;
        }
        else
        {
            //returning an empty list.
            return new List<MyDataPoco>();
        }
    }
}
```

MyDataPoco.cs:

```
public class MyDataPoco
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Complete source: [Q11874496WebApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11874496WebApp.7z)

Comment: Hi Hailton, can i assign objectdatasource control to dataset. if anything is there can you suggest me some sample code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already specified which source for each parameter value in the ObjectDataSource control.

What you need to do is on the search button's click event specify the data source and explicitly bind the grid as follows:

```
gridView1.DataSource = objectDataSource1;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi Rusty Wizard, can i assign objectdatasource control to dataset. if anything is there can you suggest me some sample code

Comment: Hey Rusty wizard, is there anyway where selectmethod mentioned with object data source control to get fired on a button click. why i am asking is that the button i am talking about is a submit button it has to fire the method mentioned with object data source control by accepting the user input in the form.

Comment: @SPL To your first question, do you mean whether you could assign a DataSet to an ObjectDataSource control? If so, then yes you can. You do so by creating a methods similar to Hailton's **QueryMyDataPoco()** method except instead of returning an **IEnumerable<MyDataPoco>** you return a **DataSet**. 

As for your question that's covered in my reply above. Let me know if it's not very clear.

Comment: Hey Rusty Wizard, my question for you is can we handle the object data source like a event instead of it doing everything at page_load()

Comment: @SPL I'm sorry but I don't understand what you meant by using the ObjectDataSource as an event.

Comment: Hey Rusty, here is a different question for you  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1"  
            TypeName="WebApplication45.App_Code.simple" SelectMethod="sing" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ObjectDataSource> for the above selectmethod i want to  pass class a=new class(); i want to pass a to the above method how can i do that

Comment: @SPL Do you mean you want to change the SelectMethod at run-time?

Comment: No.But wanted to know how to pass object a of class as parameter to selectmethod of objectdatasource

Comment: @SPL Do you mean like to take the value of a textbox or drop down list and pass that value as a parameter?

Comment: No, i want to pass class object as a parameter not the textbox or dropdown i know how to do with these. i tried passing the class object using session parameter but on reaching the value from the session field is showing null. Let me make it clear for you  class a=new class(); session["two"]=a now i am calling the select method and the value of a it is showing null and it is throwing a error object reference not set to instance of a object.

Comment: @SPL Oh right. I think I finally understood what you mean. I haven't done that before. Maybe the following link might be of some help (specifically the **Passing Custom Parameter Types** section)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx